# Error while instantiating H2 with Hikari CP

Tags: spring-boot, h2, hikaricp

I am trying to setup H2 as in memory database for my test environment with spring boot. I have configured my application as:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.platform=postgres

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

But I am getting this error:
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:h2:mem:test

I am using Hikari version 3.2.0.

Comment: So you configure H2 but expect Postgres? How should that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you used postgresql configuration. Below a configuration with hikari and H2

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.database=h2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) or [specific answer from forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/hikari-cp/ReQVNASu-w0) which define H2 database with a different driver:

```
 org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
```